# Python, QT and pyQt GUI

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm very new to python and Qt, it's only been 2 week since I started learning python. I'm working on a personal project, machine construction is in it's final stage. It's 3d plotter kinda device. currently i'm manually sending gcodes. I stared developing a simple GUI using python, Qt and pyQt for the purpose.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'GUIv0.1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(869, 927)
        self.XYcoordinates_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.XYcoordinates_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 241, 301))
        self.XYcoordinates_tbox.setObjectName("XYcoordinates_tbox")
        self.XYcoordinates_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.XYcoordinates_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 231, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.XYcoordinates_label.setFont(font)
        self.XYcoordinates_label.setObjectName("XYcoordinates_label")
        self.Xcoordinate_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Xcoordinate_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 60, 51, 41))
        self.Xcoordinate_tbox.setObjectName("Xcoorbdinate_tbox")
        self.Ycoordinate_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Ycoordinate_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 60, 51, 41))
        self.Ycoordinate_tbox.setObjectName("Ycoordinate_tbox")
        self.X_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.X_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 30, 31, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.X_label.setFont(font)
        self.X_label.setObjectName("X_label")
        self.Y_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Y_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 30, 31, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Y_label.setFont(font)
        self.Y_label.setObjectName("Y_label")
        self.XYcoordinate_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.XYcoordinate_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 70, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.XYcoordinate_label.setFont(font)
        self.XYcoordinate_label.setObjectName("XYcoordinate_label")
        self.XY_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.XY_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 60, 61, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.XY_button.setFont(font)
        self.XY_button.setObjectName("XY_button")
        self.XYspeed_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.XYspeed_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 140, 81, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.XYspeed_label.setFont(font)
        self.XYspeed_label.setObjectName("XYspeed_label")
        self.XYspeed_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.XYspeed_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 130, 131, 41))
        self.XYspeed_tbox.setObjectName("XYspeed_tbox")
        self.Gengoce_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Gengoce_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 830, 291, 71))
        self.Gengoce_button.setObjectName("Gengoce_button")
        self.Impdepth_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Impdepth_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 190, 131, 41))
        self.Impdepth_tbox.setObjectName("Impdepth_tbox")
        self.Impdepth_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Impdepth_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 200, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Impdepth_label.setFont(font)
        self.Impdepth_label.setObjectName("Impdepth_label")
        self.Displiq_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Displiq_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 460, 131, 41))
        self.Displiq_tbox.setObjectName("Displiq_tbox")
        self.Displiq_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Displiq_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 470, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Displiq_label.setFont(font)
        self.Displiq_label.setObjectName("Displiq_label")
        self.Impspeed_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Impspeed_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 250, 131, 41))
        self.Impspeed_tbox.setObjectName("Impspeed_tbox")
        self.Impspeed_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Impspeed_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 260, 171, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Impspeed_label.setFont(font)
        self.Impspeed_label.setObjectName("Impspeed_label")
        self.Xoffset_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Xoffset_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 320, 51, 41))
        self.Xoffset_tbox.setObjectName("Xoffset_tbox")
        self.Xoffset_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Xoffset_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 330, 111, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Xoffset_label.setFont(font)
        self.Xoffset_label.setObjectName("Xoffset_label")
        self.Yoffset_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Yoffset_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 320, 51, 41))
        self.Yoffset_tbox.setObjectName("Yoffset_tbox")
        self.mlperrev_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.mlperrev_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 400, 131, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.mlperrev_label.setFont(font)
        self.mlperrev_label.setObjectName("mlperrev_label")
        self.mlperrev_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.mlperrev_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 390, 131, 41))
        self.mlperrev_tbox.setObjectName("mlperrev_tbox")
        self.Dispspeed_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Dispspeed_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 530, 141, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.Dispspeed_label.setFont(font)
        self.Dispspeed_label.setObjectName("Dispspeed_label")
        self.Dispspeed_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.Dispspeed_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 520, 131, 41))
        self.Dispspeed_tbox.setObjectName("Dispspeed_tbox")
        self.start_gcode_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.start_gcode_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 410, 241, 181))
        self.start_gcode_tbox.setObjectName("start_gcode_tbox")
        self.end_gcode_tbox = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.end_gcode_tbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 640, 241, 191))
        self.end_gcode_tbox.setObjectName("end_gcode_tbox")
        self.start_gcode_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.start_gcode_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 380, 231, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.start_gcode_label.setFont(font)
        self.start_gcode_label.setObjectName("start_gcode_label")
        self.end_gcode_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.end_gcode_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 610, 231, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.end_gcode_label.setFont(font)
        self.end_gcode_label.setObjectName("end_gcode_label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.XYcoordinates_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Coordinates;"))
        self.X_label.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
        self.Y_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Y"))
        self.XYcoordinate_label.setText(_translate("Form", "XY cordinates"))
        self.XY_button.setText(_translate("Form", "ADD"))
        self.XYspeed_label.setText(_translate("Form", "XY speed"))
        self.Gengoce_button.setText(_translate("Form", "Generate Gcode"))
        self.Impdepth_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Impression depth"))
        self.Displiq_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Dispensing liquid"))
        self.Impspeed_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Impression tool speed"))
        self.Xoffset_label.setText(_translate("Form", "XY offset"))
        self.mlperrev_label.setText(_translate("Form", "ml per revolution"))
        self.Dispspeed_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Dispensing speed"))
        self.start_gcode_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Start gcode;"))
        self.end_gcode_label.setText(_translate("Form", "End gcode;"))
        self.XY_button.clicked.connect(self.xycord_gen)
        self.Gengoce_button.clicked.connect(self.generate_gcode)


    def xycord_gen(self):

        x_cord = self.Xcoordinate_tbox.toPlainText()
        y_cord = self.Ycoordinate_tbox.toPlainText()

        print(f"{x_cord}  {y_cord}")
        #self.xyspeed()

        self.XYcoordinates_tbox.setPlainText(f"X{x_cord}  Y{y_cord}\r\n")
    '''
    def xyspeed(self):
        xy_speed = self.XYspeed_tbox.toPlainText()
        print(xyspeed)
    '''

    def generate_gcode(self):
        #self.xyspeed()
        xy_speed = self.XYspeed_tbox.toPlainText()
        imp_depth = self.Impdepth_tbox.toPlainText()
        imp_speed = self.Impspeed_tbox.toPlainText()
        x_offset = self.Xoffset_tbox.toPlainText()
        y_offset = self.Yoffset_tbox.toPlainText()
        ml_rev = self.mlperrev_tbox.toPlainText()
        disp_liq = self.Displiq_tbox.toPlainText()
        disp_speed = self.Dispspeed_tbox.toPlainText()

        gcode_start = self.start_gcode_tbox.toPlainText()
        gcode_end = self.end_gcode_tbox.toPlainText()

        print(f"xy_speed: {xy_speed} mm/sec")
        print(f"imp_depth: {imp_depth} mm")
        print(f"imp_speed: {imp_speed} mm/sec")
        print(f"Offset --> X: {x_offset} Y: {y_offset} mm")
        print(f"ml_rev: {ml_rev} ml")
        print(f"disp_liquid: {disp_liq} ml")
        print(f"disp_speed: {disp_speed} mm/sec")
        print(f"start_gcode: {gcode_start}")
        print(f"end_gcode: {gcode_end}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Screen shot]

I can give **X** and **Y** position in the **text box**, and when I click **ADD** it would display on the **Coordinates; text box**. What I want is after entering **first X, Y values** and upon clicking **ADD**, it should clear current X and Y values from the text box so that I can enter new values. Currently I manually delete old values from box to enter new values. Also, after entering new values and **ADDing** it, it should be shown on **coordinates;** text box below the previous value

```
G28           ; start gcode
                                                            _
T0                                                           |            
G0 F3000      ; F<xy speed>                                  |
G0 X20 Y20    ; X<x_coord> Y<y_coord>                        |
G0 F2000      ; F<impression tool speed>                     |
G92 E0                                                       |
G1 E10        ; E<impression depth>                          |
G1 E0                                                        |---> Block 1
                                                             |
T1                                                           |
G0 X15 Y15     ; X[x_coord - x_offset] Y[y_coord - y_offset] |
G92 E0                                                       |
G1 E10 F500    ; E<10*(dispensing liquid/ml per revolution)> |
G4 P500                                                      |
                                                                  _
T0                                                                 |
G0 F3000                                                           |
G0 X30 Y30     ; X<x_coord> Y<y_coord> here new x and y coordinates|
G0 F2000                                                           |
G92 E0                                                             |
G1 E10                                                             |
G1 E0                                                              |
                                                                   |->Block2
T1                                                                 |
G0 X25 Y25 F1000      ; new x and y coordinates - offset           |
G92 E0                                                             |
G1 E10 F500                                                        |
G4 P500                                                            |
           
;remaining blocks if any
                                                  
G28 X   ;end gcode
```

Above is what my output should look like. No of Blocks in this code will be same as number of X, Y coordinate pairs added. Difference between each block is only in change of X and Y values in `G0 X<x_coord> Y<y_coord>` and `G0 X<x_coord - x_offset> Y<y_coord - y_offset>`

when clicking **Generate Gcode** button, it should produce a file with code similar to above(if possible with an extension .gcode or .txt in that case I will have save it as .gcode in notepad++)

SO how should I save the X and Y coordinates that I enter through text box. Is tuple a good choice?? how can I add enter x and y values to a tuple?

I don't if this is the right platform for this question. If not please redirect me.

suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Figured out how to clear and append text box